# Reading data from a Firebase Realtime Database and sorting it by value - iOS Mobile Development- Swift

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, sorting

I am trying to read in these key-value pairs from my Firebase Realtime Database. I want to save these key-value pairs somehow so I can sort them by their value, and then display those values. I am essentially attempting to create a high-scores page in my app that will display a table.
For example I would like them to be displayed as:
Jenny - 10 
Ross - 4 
Kim - 1 
Billy - 0 
I do not know how I can get the key-value pair into this format.
This is how I take 2 players data and push it onto the Firebase Database:

```
func PopulateDatabaseWithScores() {
        let currentPlayers = [PlayerData.playerNames[0] : PlayerData.playerScores[0] , <br>PlayerData.playerNames[1] : PlayerData.playerScores[1]]
        HighScoresViewController.ref.updateChildValues(currentPlayers)
        }
```

This is currently how I am getting data and attempting to sort it:

```
HighScoresViewController.database.child("Users&Scores").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            
            let usersAndScoresDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Int] ?? [:] //non sorted dictionary
            let sortedByValueDictionary = usersAndScoresDictionary.sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 } .map {$0} //this is the sorted dictionary
            
            print("Before Sorting...\n")
            let dictKeys = Array(usersAndScoresDictionary.keys)
            print (dictKeys)
        let dictValues = Array(usersAndScoresDictionary.values)
        print(dictValues)
        
        print("\nAfter Sorting...\n")
        print(sortedByValueDictionary)
        
        
        print ("\nNew testing for sorting and obtaining data...")
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        
        
        print (value)
```

This is what my ouput looks like in the terminal while the app loads in the HighScores page:

```
Before Sorting...

["Billy", "Aang", "Pants", "Jobby", "BillyBobby", "Jello", "Boss", "Janice", "Toff", "SuzyQueIloveYou", "Lameron", "Nanet"]
[2, 5, 3, 6, 2, 1, 0, 4, 1, 4, 7, 8]

After Sorting...

[(key: "Nanet", value: 8), (key: "Lameron", value: 7), (key: "Jobby", value: 6), (key: "Aang", value: 5), (key: "Janice", value: 4), (key: "SuzyQueIloveYou", value: 4), (key: "Pants", value: 3), (key: "Billy", value: 2), (key: "BillyBobby", value: 2), (key: "Jello", value: 1), (key: "Toff", value: 1), (key: "Boss", value: 0)]

New testing for sorting and obtaining data...
Optional({
    Aang = 5;
    Billy = 2;
    BillyBobby = 2;
    Boss = 0;
    Janice = 4;
    Jello = 1;
    Jobby = 6;
    Lameron = 7;
    Nanet = 8;
    Pants = 3;
    SuzyQueIloveYou = 4;
    Toff = 1;
})
```

I have been able to get the data from the database, but I do not know how to get it and store it so I can use it for later. For example, what I am thinking that I need to be able to do is save each key-value pair as an object, and then put that object in an array. Then I would like to sort that array by the objects value. This is my train of thought, any help would be greatly appreciated! I have heard of dictionaries, but I am not familiar with how those work. 
The long term idea for this is that users will be able to create a profile, play the game, and their data will be updated in the database. This data would be their username and wins. Then when a user loads the highscores page, a table will populate and be sorted by the most wins.

Answer (score 0):

To store value fetched from database you can have a model class with Codeable protocol. For that please have a look at [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) and [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/119/codable-cheat-sheet)

For retrieving data and showing it to user you can use tableview and you can pass a single object of your model in tableview cellForRowAt indexpath and update your tableview cell accordingly.